# Show that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Show that $f_n(x) = \frac {n+\cos(x)}{ne^x+\sin(x)}$ converges uniformly.

I think it converges uniformly to $\frac {1}{e^x}.$ But, I am struggling to prove this with the formal definition.

Attempt: $\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists M\in N$ such that for $n\ge M,$ $$\left|\frac {n+\cos(x)}{ne^x+\sin(x)}-\frac {1}{e^x}\right|=\left|\frac {1+\frac{\cos(x)}{n}}{e^x+\frac{\sin(x)}{n}}-\frac{1}{e^x}\right|\to\left|\frac{1}{e^x}-\frac{1}{e^x}\right|=0<\varepsilon$$ for all $x \in R.$  Is this okay? Is there another way to show this?

Edit: The original question is:

Consider the sequence of functions $$f_n(x) = \frac {n+\cos(x)}{ne^x+\sin(x)}, n=1,2,...$$ Compute the following limit of integrals $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac {n+\cos(x)}{ne^x+\sin(x)}dx.$$

I was trying to solve this question by using the theorem that if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n = \int f.$ If $f_n$ does not converges uniformly to $f$, how can we solve this question?

Comment: No it's not. The point is not about showing the *limit* is less than epsilon, but showing the *finite difference* is.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you are aware that you should show the choice of $M$ is not dependent on $x$, which is why we call the convergence uniform.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of the difference between pointwise and uniform convergence. But, I don't understand your first point. According to my text, this is the definition of uniform convergence (using $\varepsilon$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact the convergence is only pointwise but not uniform. To see this, you can pick a sequence of $x$, say $x_n:=-2n\pi$, then 
$$|f_n(x_n)-e^{-x_n}|=\frac1ne^{2n\pi}$$
Which blows up and clearly doesn't converge to zero. And hence you should see that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ (in fact all of them, in this particular case) such that whatever $M\in\Bbb N$ you choose, you can always find some $n>M$ such that
$\sup_x |f_n(x)-e^{-x}|\ge\epsilon.$

What does uniform convergence mean, intuitively? You can picture it this way: if we have $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly *on* some interval $I$ (the specification of the domain of convergence is extremely important for us to decide whether the convergence is uniform or not), it means that given any $\epsilon>0$, if you draw a $\pm\epsilon$ vertical band around the graph of $f$ over $I$ then as $n$ goes past some point ($M$) the graph of $f_n$ will stay within that band henceforth forever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you see my edit and give some comment?

Comment: @SihyunKim now that you specify your domain as $[0,1]$, then yes the convergence is uniform (originally I thought you were talking about $\Bbb R$). Are you able to modify your previous epsilon-delta language to prove it?

Comment: Sorry. It's my fault. After I specify the domain, is my epsilon-delta proof still wrong?

Comment: @SihyunKim as I said in my comment yesterday: show the finite difference is less than epsilon, not the limit; show the choice of M is independent of $x$.

Comment: Ok. $|\frac {n+\cos(x)}{ne^x+\sin(x)}-\frac {1}{e^x}|\le |\frac {n+\cos(x)}{ne^x}-\frac {1}{e^x}| \le |\frac {n}{ne^x} - \frac {1}{e^x}|$. Here, I am not sure how to eliminate $\cos(x).$

Comment: @SihyunKim it's smaller than 1.

Comment: Yes. But, $|\frac {n+\cos(x)}{ne^x}|\not\le |\frac {n}{ne^x}|$

Comment: @SihyunKim i mean you can write it like $|(n+1)/ne^x-1/e^x|$

Answer (score 1):

$f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ in $\mathbb R$.

However, $f_n$ converges UNIFORMLY to $f$ in every interval of the form $[x_0,\infty)$, where $x_0\in\mathbb R$.